# Compiling software in Ubuntu 10.10 and creating working shortcuts through sub-menus

Tags: 10.10, software-center, blender

A few subjects that I've found considerable lack of documentation on is the downloading of software outside of each distro's respective package manager, compiling it, and executing a working program of the likes of Windows. I've tried the command line, the Synaptic Package Manager, all to no avail.

All of this is within a custom distro known as OpenArtist, currently based off of Ubuntu Maverick (www.openartisthq.com), and what I meainly want to achieve is to creating working shortcuts within submenus as well as download, find, and execute working applications possibly outside of the more popular distros' package managers and then create a path to be launched within a menu.

I am new to Linux and am fairly unsure as to where I can find information regarding this.

If you'd like a specific example, OpenArtist houses a menu upon the panel known as "3D." What I would like to accomplish is downloading Blender 2.62 and then creating a working path to launch the program. I would like to do this with several other programs, but figure that if I can resolve this, anything else should come easily.

Thanks! :3

Answer (score 0):

The package manager includes a massive wealth of software. Installing from source will always be a challenge. There are basic guides on installing software from source (running `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`) but you will have to read the output to see if you're missing dependencies, then you may have to search the web for those dependencies to find out which packages contain them. If it installs but just says there's an error installing it, go to the package manager to fix broken packages, and all is resolved.

To edit the applications menu, make sure you have the menu editor installed: `sudo apt-get install alacarte`, then you can run `alacarte` and edit your menus. You can easily create, delete and edit launchers in the Menu Editor.

If you install Blender, it should automatically add itself to the applications menu. Installing software from source usually does this, too. If it doesn't show up automatically, you can go into the Menu Editor and find them in their respective categories, then uncheck and re-check them.